# How do I restrict angular-xeditable to only positive numbers?

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I have the following code.  Is there an attribute to restrict to just positive numbers?

```
<td><span e-step="0.001" editable-number="myNumber" onaftersave="updateValue()">{{ myNumber }} </span></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `e-min="0"` to set the minimum value 
and  `e-max="100"` to set a maximum.